# Repartition in Spark during Write with Partitionby

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using spark 1.6 and trying to write a large Dataframe of Size 11GB using below statement but it's giving me may be due to large partition size of 2GB+

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE


df.write.mode("append").partitionBy("audit_month").parquet("/data/sometable")
```

Is there any workaround available for this to create multiple partitions internally while writing but i want to keep end result as  /data/sometable/audit_month=08-2018/ ?.

Comment: partitionBy does not repartiton, you should try to increase the dataframe partitions, e.g. df.repartition(100).write.mode("append").partitionBy("audit_month").parquet("/data/sometable")

Comment: Thanks., trying now . Is there a way to see that in Spark logs of 100 partitions being generated ?.

Comment: I see message like the below now  INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on localhost:42242 (size: 8.0 KB, free: 11.8 GB)

Comment: @RaphaelRoth, Looks like your solution is not working, this time my write method just hung now. I had to do ctrl+C after a long time.

Comment: Is it really hung? Open the Spark UI to watch the progress... The point is that it doesn't crash otherwise

Comment: Repartition is a fairly heavy operation. You might be hung due to memory issues caused by shuffling of data, that occurs inside cluster, in case the data is heavy. Flippo Loddo's answer is a smart hack, or you can look into Coalesce() method as well.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

df.write.mode("append").parquet("/data/sometable/audit_month="+audit_month)